# Formatear el nombre de un archivo a guardar Java - Spring MVC/Struts2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts2

Estoy buscando la forma de al momento de guardar un archivo si bien tengo la logica para capturalo lo estoy guardando con el nombre que tiene la imagen, lo que yo quisiera hacer es capturar el archivo y darle yo formato al nombre por ejemplo

Nombre_archivo_Fecha para poder evitar en caso de subir un archivo que tenga el mismo se pisen.

Actualmente lo estoy realizando de esta manera en struts2 tambien quisiera saber la manera de realizarlo en Spring-MVc:

```
introducir el código aquí
private File userImage;
    private String userImageContentType;
    private String userImageFileName;

    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception{
         try {
                String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/productos");

             System.out.println("FilePatch: " + filePath);
             System.out.println("Genero: " + genero);
                File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);
                FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
                nombreimagen = "images/productos/"+userImageFileName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [UUID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal) para evitar duplicados

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

String filePath = ...
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(this.userImageFileName); // de org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

File file = new File(filePath + uuid.toString() + "." + extension);
```

Como estos datos regularmente los guardo en la base de datos, tengo un campo para el nombre original, por ejemplo si subes `foto1.jpg` puedes tener en tu base

```
Archivo
| ID | nombreOriginal | path
| 1  | foto.jpg       | 7483e87d-e249-4110-bc3c-0ee76396ce01.jpg
```

O simplmente puedes guadar con el ID del registro

```
Archivo
| ID | nombreOriginal 
| 1  | foto.jpg
```

Y tenerlo en tu sistema de archivos

```
/ruta/a/archivos/1
```

Para cuando quieras descargar el archivo puedas consultar su nombre original y en base a su extensión puedas asignar el `content type` adecuado

```
response.setContentType
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede servir para el formato que quieres lograr:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    static final SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd-HH-mm-ss-SS");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombreOriginal = "foto.jpg";
        String nombre, extension;

        int punto = nombreOriginal.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (punto > 0) {
            nombre = nombreOriginal.substring(0, punto);
            extension = "." + nombreOriginal.substring(punto + 1);
        } else {
            nombre = nombreOriginal;
            extension = "";
        }
        String fecha = formateador.format(new Date());
        String nombreDeArchivo = String.format("%s_%s%s", nombre, fecha, extension);
        System.out.println(nombreDeArchivo);
    }
}
```

El formato de la fecha y hora lo puedes ajustar a lo que quieres lograr. El "SS" al final te da los milisegundos y normalmente eso es sufuciente para evitar colisiones de nombres.